How to pass MutableState<Boolean> to a Composable in Jetpack Compose
In an app I'm working on, I'm having trouble passing a MutableState<Boolean> from a parent composable to a child composable. The reason I want to use MutableState is that this variable will be changed in the child composable.
Here’s a simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
@Composable
fun ParentComposable(
    screenHeight: Dp,
    barHeight: Dp,
) {
    var scrollEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = barHeight)
            .height(screenHeight - barHeight)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        UserButtons(
            scrollEnabled = scrollEnabled // the error occurs here 
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun UserButtons(
    scrollEnabled: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            scrollEnabled.value = false
            println("Scroll has been deactivated")
        }) {}
}


The error message I get is:

Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean but MutableState was expected

I'm guessing that the issue is when passing scrollEnabled (which is the MutableState<Boolean>) to the child composable UserButtons; for some reason it's detected as a normal Boolean even if it's declared as a MutableState<Boolean>.
How can I make sure that the parameter is correctly detected as an MutableState?


The reason I want to use MutableState is that this variable will be changed in the child composable.

You should not do that. Jetpack Compose uses the unidirectional data flow pattern. That means that

data only flows downwards the Composable hierarchy using function parameters
events only flow upwards the Composable hierarchy using callback functions

That means that you should not pass a MutableState<T> to a child Composable, because when the child Composable modifies data from the parent Composable, the data flows upwards. Instead, use a callback function to notify the parent Composable to update the value of the scrollEnabled variable:
@Composable
fun UserButtons(
    scrollEnabled: Boolean,
    updateScrollEnabled: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            updateScrollEnabled(false)
            println("Scroll has been deactivated")
        }
    ) {
        //...
    }
}

In your ParentComposable, call the UserButtons Composable like this:
UserButtons(
    scrollEnabled = scrollEnabled,  // data flowing downwards
    updateScrollEnabled = { updatedValue ->
        scrollEnabled = updatedValue  // event flowing upwards
    }
)


Side Note
The reason you were getting the type mismatch is because you were using the by keyword, which transforms a MutableState<T> into T by calling the getValue function of MutableState.  So, doing
val scrollEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Text(text = "scrollEnabled: ${scrollEnabled.value})

is the same as
var scrollEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Text(text = "scrollEnabled: ${scrollEnabled})

only that it is shorter and more convenient to use. As a third option, you can already obtain a setScrollEnabled function at the declaration directly like this:
val (scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Finally, set it directly as the updateScrollEnabled function:
UserButtons(
    scrollEnabled = scrollEnabled,  // data flowing downwards
    updateScrollEnabled = setScrollEnabled
)

This third approach especially pays off if you have many child Composables that are requesting the parent Composable to update a value.

Thank you, this worked!
I had to clue that Jetpack Compuse used that data flow pattern.
PS. I think that updateValue is missing an arrow -> in your answer

Happy to help and thanks for the hint, indeed the arrow was missing. I edited my post accordingly.

and instead of creating { updatedValue -> scrollEnabled = updatedValue } callback its better to use val (scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }, more: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state#state-in-composables (the third option you did not mention here)

@pskink That's indeed another option to write it, although I wouldn't say it's inherently better to use that. As the documentation states, These declarations are equivalent, and are provided as syntax sugar for different uses of state. You should pick the one that produces the easiest-to-read code in the composable you're writing.

it is better as you dont have to write your callback - you already have it - especialy when you are passing it to several Composables

@pskink When you have several child Composables updating the parent Composables value, it indeed pays off. I edited my post and added that case for completeness. Thank you.

sure, your welcome
